# How to understand the output of route

Tags: route

Saying that I'm configuring the network of an Ubuntu system. So I may edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` as below:

```
...
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Then I execute the command `route` and I can get such an output:

```
default       gateway    genmask
192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0
```

I don't know how can I understand `192.168.1.0`, `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route man page explains it pretty well:

```
OUTPUT
   The output of the kernel routing table is organized in the following columns

   Destination
          The destination network or destination host.

   Gateway
          The gateway address or '*' if none set.

   Genmask
          The netmask for the destination net; '255.255.255.255' for a host destination and '0.0.0.0' for the default route.
```

So 192.168.1.0 is your destination network, 0.0.0.0 is your gateway and 255.255.255.0 is your netmask.
If you're in doubt why your gateway is 0.0.0.0 [this answer explains it pretty well](https://superuser.com/questions/872479/what-does-0-0-0-0-gateway-mean-in-routing-table).

Comment: what is destination network? why is it `192.168.1.0`, instead of `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is an IP address and is your gateway in this case. 192.168.1.0 means the whole network based on the netmask. In this case the destination network is 192.168.1.*

Answer (score 9):

A quick example may help.
Presume this route table entry (from 'route -an' command output under Linux, and not all columns shown, only the ones we need - and this is the 'winning' entry, other entries not shown):

```
Destination   Gateway  Genmask          Iface
192.168.69.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0    eth7
.... other entries not shown ....
```

Now assume we are routing an outbound packet whose destination IP is 192.168.69.25. These are the steps that occur. They occur (in theory) for every entry in the route table; we are only showing the 'winning' entry.

```
Extract destination IP:  192.168.69.25
AND it with the Genmask: 192.168.69.25 AND 255.255.255.0 ==> 192.168.69.0
Match the result against the 'Destination' field of the entry.
They match:   192.168.69.0 matches 92.168.69.0
The entry matches (and we presume it's the 'best' match, for simplicity).
```

The Gateway field of the matching entry is 0.0.0.0, meaning 'no gateway, none needed'. It means that IPs that match this entry are directly available to this host and can be reached using the specified interface 'eth7'. Send an ARP for 192.168.69.25 onto the network to which eth7 is connected; there should be a reply with that host's MAC. Send the packet to that MAC address.

If the Gateway is not 0.0.0.0, it is expected to be the IP of a device found on the eth7 network. Send an ARP for the Gateway out eth7 and get the reply. Send the packet to that ARP. This is typically a router, which will receive the packet and forward it to the appropriate next hop network.

This is a short and sweet example - you can find more elaboration with a bit of searching...